# Remove index from duplicate column string value when converting to my CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe and write data in Excel sheet than I try to convert into a csv. When converting into a csv I want to get data like this :

[image]

Instead I'am getting something like this in my CSV:

[image]

My dataframe looks something like this :

```
    valueDict = {
                 "Custom field (Standard)":["Custom field (Standard)"],
                 "Custom field2 (Standard)":["Custom field (Standard)"],
                 "Custom field3 (Standard)":["Custom field (Standard)"],
}
```

I tried something like this :

```
    readExcel.to_csv("./FileName.csv", sep=";", index=False, index_label=False)
```

But it did not work. Anyone have an idea how can I remove index from duplicate values ?. My dataframe needs to be in that form (dictionnary of lists) and first value is the header and i write in xlsx before converting to csv. Thank you in advance for any kind of help

Comment: Could you include a small example dataframe / input data that illustrates the problem?

Comment: The problem @Shaido is first value of each list in the dataframe is written in the csv with index because it the same value. "Custom field (Standard)" is converted into "Custom field (Standard).1" in csv

Comment: The `to_csv` method will not change any column names even if they are the same (at least not according to the small test I did). The `.1` and `.2` were probably added when you read the dataframe from the excel file. In this case, what you can do is rename the columns before writing to the csv file but I'm not sure exactly how the dataframe looks so I can't really answer any more exact than this.

Comment: @Shaido The dataframe looks like this : ```` valueDict = {
                 "Custom field (Standard)":["Custom field (Standard)"],
                 "Custom field2 (Standard)":["Custom field (Standard)"],
                 "Custom field3 (Standard)":["Custom field (Standard)"],
}``` and ```df = pd.DataFrame(valueDict)```` I don't see how the problem exist in the dataframe because when writing to excel there is no problem

Comment: Using the `df` as in your comment, I can't replicate the problem. The csv file looks correct (one header with `Custom field (Standard);Custom field2 (Standard);Custom field3 (Standard)` and one line with `Custom field (Standard);Custom field (Standard);Custom field (Standard)`).

Comment: @Shaido your previous comment helped me to find the problem. In fact, I was reading the xlsx file and then converting it into a csv ```` readExcel = pd.read_excel("./File_Output.xlsx") ```` This line while reading the Excel file add index when column name are the same. I deleted it and I replaced with converting directly into csv ```` df.to_csv("./File_Output.csv", encoding='utf-8', sep=';', header=None, index=False, index_label=False) ````